# dovecot mysql-connection error because of special charater in config

Tags: mysql, sql, dovecot

I successful set up my Server with froxlor, etc. but now I get errros with my mail delivery Agent because I use a '#' in my mysql-pw. I tried to escape it with a '\' but it doens't seem to work. :(

How can I change the /etc/dovecot/covecot-sql.conf.ext to make it working with my password with the special character (lets take as example pw "test#this)?

Mycurrent config:

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=froxlor user=froxlor password=test#test
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

This is the error message:

```
dovecot: auth: Warning: Configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext line 2: Ambiguous '#' character in line, treating it as comment. Add a space before it to remove this warning.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dovecot [wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL)

`# Use "host= ... pass=foo#bar" if your password has '#' character`

so your `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` should be

```
driver = mysql
connect = "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=froxlor user=froxlor password=test#test"
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

Comment: btw: how to mark a question as answered?

Comment: didn't work for me. The special character being space instead of #